# Measuring elapsed time in python

Tags: python, windows, time, duration

Is there a simple way / module to *correctly* measure the elapsed time in python? I know that I can simply call `time.time()` twice and take the difference, but that will yield wrong results if the system time is changed. Granted, that doesn't happen very often, but it does indicate that I'm measuring the wrong thing.

Using `time.time()` to measure durations is incredibly roundabout when you think about it. You take the difference of two absolute time measurements which are in turn constructed from duration measurements (performed by timers) and known absolute times (set manually or via ntp), that you aren't interested in at all.

So, is there a way to query this "timer time" directly? I'd imagine that it can be represented as a millisecond or microsecond value that has no meaningful absolute representation (and thus doesn't need to be adjusted with system time). Looking around a bit it seems that this is exactly what `System.nanoTime()` does in Java, but I did not find a corresponding Python function, even though it should (hardware-technically) be easier to provide than `time.time()`.

Edit: To avoid confusion and address the answers below: This is not about DST changes, and I don't want CPU time either - I want elapsed physical time. It doesn't need to be very fine-grained, and not even particularly accurate. It just shouldn't give me negative durations, or durations which are off by several orders of magnitude (above the granularity), just because someone decided to set the system clock to a different value. Here's what the Python docs say about 'time.time()':

["While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls"](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time)

This is exactly what I want to avoid, since it can lead to strange things like negative values in time calculations. I can work around this at the moment, but I believe it is a good idea to learn using the proper solutions where feasible, since the kludges will come back to bite you one day.

Edit2: Some research shows that you can get a system time independent measurement like I want in Windows by using GetTickCount64(), under Linux you can get it in the return value of times(). However, I still can't find a module which provides this functionality in Python.

Comment: If you want to benchmark something, you should use `timeit`.

Comment: related: [How do I get monotonic time durations in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205722/how-do-i-get-monotonic-time-durations-in-python)

Comment: You may be experiencing the [Microsoft Minute](http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/99mar/19990318.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `perf_counter` function of time module in Python Standard Library:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from time import perf_counter

startTime = perf_counter()
CallYourFunc()
finishedTime = perf_counter()
duration = timedelta(seconds=(finishedTime - startTime))
```

Comment: I looked around a bit and this is probably the option most people should use these days (either this or time.monotonic), so the accepted answer moves here.

Answer (score 27):

For measuring elapsed CPU time, look at [time.clock()](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2007-January/1121263.html). This is the equivalent of Linux's [times()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) user time field.

For benchmarking, use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

The [datetime module](http://effbot.org/librarybook/datetime.htm), [which is part of Python 2.3+](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html), also has microsecond time if supported by the platform.

Example:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> n1=dt.datetime.now()
>>> n2=dt.datetime.now()
>>> (n2-n1).microseconds
678521
>>> (n2.microsecond-n1.microsecond)/1e6
0.678521
ie, it took me .678521 seconds to type the second n2= line -- slow
>>> n1.resolution
datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 1)
1/1e6 resolution is claimed.
```

If you are concerned about system time changes (from DS -> ST) just check the object returned by datetime.Presumably, the system time could have a small adjustment from an [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) reference adjustment. [This should be slewed](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#), and corrections are [applied gradually](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm#Q-ALGO-CLK-UPD), but ntp sync beats can have an effect with very small (millisec or microsec) time references.

You can also reference [Alex Martelli's C function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110063/python-clock-function-on-freebsd/1110113#1110113) if you want something of that resolution. I would not go too far to reinvent the wheel. Accurate time is basic and most modern OS's do a pretty good job.

**Edit**

Based on your clarifications, it sounds like you need a simple side check if the system's clock has changed. Just compare to a friendly, local ntp server:

```
import socket
import struct
import time

ntp="pool.ntp.org"   # or whatever ntp server you have handy

client = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
data = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'
client.sendto( data, ( ntp, 123 ))
data, address = client.recvfrom( 1024 )
if data:
    print 'Response received from:', address
    t = struct.unpack( '!12I', data )[10]
    t -= 2208988800L #seconds since Epoch
    print '\tTime=%s' % time.ctime(t)
```

NTP is accurate to milliseconds over the Internet and has representation resolution of resolution of 2−32 seconds (233 picoseconds). Should be good enough?

Be aware that the NTP 64 bit data structure [will overflow in 2036 and every 136 years thereafter](http://www.beaglesoft.com/Manual/page53.htm) -- if you really want a robust solution, better check for overflow...

Comment: +1 for the slewing information, which mitigates the problem. However, I'm not after higher granularity. In fact, in my current application, seconds would be fine.

Comment: I don't think an NTP server query is an elegant solution. After all, there is dedicated hardware for measuring what I want build into basically every PC, and it can be queried by system functions on both Windows and Linux - see my new edit above.

Comment: @Medo42: You wouldn't need to do the ntp call each timer instance; only if `time.time()` returned a negative number or something unexpected. [Pyson's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421641/measuring-elapsed-time-in-python/7423817#7423817) method of comparing to `time.clock()` has merit. You could use something like that to trigger when to do a comparison to an outside source. Personally, the OS time is good enough for millisecond+ timing for me. Using a HW timer has its own accuracy concerns.

Comment: Note that the example is misleading in stating that it took ".678521 seconds to type the second n2= line".  The 'microseconds' method only returns the microseconds portion of the time difference.  Calling 'seconds' returns the seconds portion of the time.  The total time is actually (n2-n1).seconds + (n2-n1).microseconds/1e6.  Alternatively, it's possible to call (n2-n1).total_seconds() to get the two parts combined.

Answer (score 12):

What you seem to be looking for is a [monotonic timer](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). A [monotonic time reference](http://markmail.org/thread/54bb663vi47kjxnu) does not jump or go backwards.

There have been several attempts to implement a cross platform monotomic clock for Python based on the OS reference of it. (Windows, POSIX and BSD are quite different) See the discussions and some of the attempts at monotonic time in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687408/retrieve-wall-time-in-python-using-the-standard-library/4687457#4687457).

Mostly, you can just use os.times():

> os.times()
>
> Return a 5-tuple of floating point numbers indicating
> accumulated (processor or other) times, in seconds. The items are:
> user time, system time, children’s user time, children’s system time,
> and elapsed real time since a fixed point in the past, in that order.
> See the Unix manual page times(2) or the corresponding Windows
> Platform API documentation. On Windows, only the first two items are
> filled, the others are zero.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows

But that does not fill in the needed elapsed real time (the fifth tuple) on Windows.

If you need Windows support, consider `ctypes` and you can call GetTickCount64() directly, as has been done in [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576786-detect-when-system-is-idle/).

Comment: I wonder why nobody has proposed adding the 5th tuple value to os.times on Windows? Seems like it should be possible, as the reference point isn't specified.

Comment: @Mark Ransome: Not being a Winoze guy, but perhaps because something like `GetTickCount64()` or the 32 version of same is not in the core Windows API that is assumed in the baseline for cPython? i.e., legacy support on that platform? Don't know otherwise. Monotonic time ref  is a useful feature.

Answer (score 12):

Python 3.3 added a [monotonic timer](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0418/#time-monotonic) into the standard library, which does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to Paddy3118 for pointing this out in ["How do I get monotonic time durations in python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14416514/575615).

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t1=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> t2=datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> t2-t1
datetime.timedelta(0, 8, 600000)
```

Using UTC avoids those embarassing periods when the clock shifts due to daylight saving time.

As for using an alternate method rather than subtracting two clocks, be aware that the OS does actually contain a clock which is initialized from a hardware clock in the PC. Modern OS implementations will also keep that clock synchronized with some official source so that it doesn't drift. This is much more accurate than any interval timer the PC might be running.

Comment: More accurate - yes, in the long term. This clock time can behave strangely though in the instant it is adjusted (unless the adjustment is slewed, as described in drewk's answer). I don't need high accuracy over long times, but I want reliable short-term measurements that don't give negative or way too large intervals just because someone decided to manually change the system time - which does happen sometimes.

Comment: tElapsed = datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(t2-t1) in Python 3.6

Answer (score 2):

The example functions you state in your edit are two completely different things:

1. Linux [times()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times) returns process times in CPU milliseconds. Python's equivalent is time.clock() or `os.times()`.
2. Windows [GetTickCount64()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns system uptime.

Although two different functions, both (potentially) could be used to reveal a system clock that had a "burp" with these methods:

**First:**

You could take both a system time with `time.time()` and a CPU time with `time.clock()`. Since wall clock time will ALWAYS be greater than or equal to CPU time, discard any measurements where  the interval between the two `time.time()` readings is less than the paired `time.clock()` check readings.

Example:

```
t1=time.time()
t1check=time.clock()

# your timed event...    

t2=time.time()
t2check=time.clock()

if t2-t1 < t2check - t1check:
    print "Things are rotten in Denmark"
    # discard that sample
else:
    # do what you do with t2 - t1...
```

**Second:**

Getting system uptime is also promising if you are concerned about the system's clock, since a user reset does not reset the uptime tick count in most cases. (that I am aware of...)

Now the harder question: getting system uptime in a platform independent way -- especially without spawning a new shell -- at the sub second accuracy. Hmmm...

Probably the best bet is [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). [Browsing the source](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=uptime+package%3ahttp://psutil%5C.googlecode%5C.com), they use `uptime = GetTickCount() / 1000.00f;` for Windows and `sysctl "kern.boottime"` for BSD / OS X, etc. Unfortunately, these are all 1 second resolution.

Comment: I was confused about times() as well in the beginning, but read your own linked manual (particularly the part that says "Return Value".) The function can be used to find process times which are filled into a provided struct, but it *returns* a system clock independend measure of time.

Comment: Is it true that wall clock time will always be greater than CPU time?  I believe this is only the case on single core systems.

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
print 'hello'
end = datetime.now()
delta = end-start
print type(delta)
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
import datetime
help(datetime.timedelta)
...elapsed seconds and microseconds...
```

Comment: This is not as useful as other answers IMO, because datetime.now() is just as susceptible to system time adjustment as time.time().

Answer (score 1):

After using time.monotonic from Python 3.3+ I found that on Mac it works well, never going backwards. On Windows, where it uses GetTickCount64() it can very rarely go backwards by a substantial amount (for the purposes of my program that was in excess of 5.0) Adding a wrapper can prevent monotonic from going backwards:

```
with a_lock:
    original_value = time.monotonic()
    if original_value < last_value:
        # You can post a metric here to monitor frequency and size of backward jumps
        offset = last_value - original_value
    last_value = original_value
    return offset + original_value
```

How often did it go backwards? Perhaps a handful of times over many days across millions of machines and again, only on Windows. Sorry, I did not track which versions of Windows. I can update this later if people wish.