# Pycurl: how to determine duration of a request

Tags: python, curl, time, pycurl

My task is to do periodic requests to server and write time of this request to database. I use Python 2.7.3, cURL and pycurl as wrapper for cURL. I do request like so:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://google.com/")
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True) # to see request details
c.perform()
```

But how I can determine the time of this request?

**UPD1**

Ok, I understand, that I should take 2 timestamps and the diff between them will be the duration of request. But I face some problem:

when I execute:

```
import pycurl, time
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://google.com/")
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True) # to see request details
ts = time.clock()
c.perform()
print time.clock() - ts
```

I get 0.0 o (sometimes) 0.01. It's wrong diff, because of I execute this commands in python shell and some time is left after I do `ts = time.clock()` and before I do `print time.clock() - ts`, so the diff should be about 3 sec.

This output I get on my Ubuntu server 12.04 installed on Virtualbox. Virtualbox installed on Windows 7. When I try code below in windows 7 I get correct output.

Here is another question - maybe I should use time.time() instead of time.clock()?

**Solution**

Idea was taken from [this post](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2008/09/python-timing-timeclock-vs-timetime.html). Succinctly, you should use time.clock() on windows and time.time() on Linux or Unix (Ubuntu and others, FreeBSD and others, MacOS). And you can also use timeit.default_timer(). This function detect os type and choose time.time() or time.clock(). So the solution's code is:

```
import pycurl, timeit
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://google.com/")
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True) # to see request details
ts = timeit.default_timer()
c.perform()
print timeit.default_timer() - ts
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring elapsed time in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421641/measuring-elapsed-time-in-python)

Comment: Are you asking for the _duration_ of the request, the local time the request began, the time when the remote server received it, something else...?

Comment: @Adrian Petrescu  the time between the moment when request sent from local machine and the moment when response reach local machine

Comment: get hold of the timestamp before and after and take the difference. where is the problem?

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary  Ping determine how fast server make the response by ICMP protocol. Usin curl I measure the time by TCP protocol - how fast web server make the response.

Answer (score 5):

After you do `curl.perform()` you can extract information from a curl handle:

```
m = {}
m['total-time'] = curl.getinfo(pycurl.TOTAL_TIME)
m['namelookup-time'] = curl.getinfo(pycurl.NAMELOOKUP_TIME)
m['connect-time'] = curl.getinfo(pycurl.CONNECT_TIME)
m['pretransfer-time'] = curl.getinfo(pycurl.PRETRANSFER_TIME)
m['redirect-time'] = curl.getinfo(pycurl.REDIRECT_TIME)
m['starttransfer-time'] = curl.getinfo(pycurl.STARTTRANSFER_TIME)
```

Docs for getinfo():
http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlobject.html#pycurl.Curl.getinfo

List of available information to get from request:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html

Answer (score 2):

```
import pycurl, time
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "http://google.com/")
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True) # to see request details
ts = time.clock()
c.perform()
print time.clock() - ts
```

Comment: thx! but here is some problem. I have primary OS win7 and python 2.7.3 installed. I also have virtualbox with ubuntu server 12.04 installed with python 2.7.3. when I execute time.clock() on win7 I get good values like 14.2348885920, but when I execute time.clock() on virtual machine I get values like 0.2, 0.4 and so on (all < 1).

Comment: If I use time.time() it's ok.

Comment: Should we know what you have tried so far? If you have a more specific problem then state this is in your question instead of letting us guess which is clearly a chance for getting downvoted.

Comment: I added description of problem with your code to question. So the question is - why I have problems with time.clock() on linux and don't have them on windows? Maybe I should simply use time.time()?

Answer (score 0):

don't use time.clock() for timing elapsed intervals.  It's also now deprecated.